# Trouble creating a List of properties of a certain type from a class using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class with (at the present time) 3 Azure CloudTable properties. I am trying to create a private method to return a list of properties of type CloudTable as there are times where I need to grab commission and fee information from all of them

Main Class

```
public class EquityAndOptionDataRetrievalManager
{
    private readonly IAzureStorageService _azureStorageService;

    public EquityAndOptionDataRetrievalManager(IAzureStorageService azureStorageService)
    {
        _azureStorageService = azureStorageService;
    }

    // properties

    public CloudTable EquityTradeRecordsTable => AzureHelpers.GetCloudTable(_azureStorageService.PrimaryConnectionString, Common.StorageTable.EquityTradeRecordsTable);

    public CloudTable OptionTradeRecordsTable => AzureHelpers.GetCloudTable(_azureStorageService.PrimaryConnectionString, Common.StorageTable.OptionTradeRecordsTable);

    public CloudTable SymbolsTradedTable => AzureHelpers.GetCloudTable(_azureStorageService.PrimaryConnectionString, Common.StorageTable.InteractiveSymbolsTraded);

...rest removed for brevity
```

and I am trying to do something like this

```
private List<CloudTable> AzureTables()
{
    var tables = new List<CloudTable>();
    var obj = new EquityAndOptionDataRetrievalManager(_azureStorageService);
    var properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    
    foreach (var p in properties)
    {
        if (p.GetType() == typeof(CloudTable))
        {
            tables.Add(p.GetValue(obj,null) as CloudTable);
        }
    }

    return tables;
}
```

but in the tables.Add(p) and using p. to see all the available properties and methods, I cannot find anything that works. Is this not doable?

Note: Per MakePeaceGreatAgain's comments

I added a property to test the method in the class

> public List AzureTableList { get; set; }

and I'm calling, just to test it
It is failing, because the if inside the foreach loop never captures the CloudTable properties, even when they actually are CloudTable properties!

It's the right type, but it exits the if statement

[image]

Comment: `P` is just the `PropertInfo`, not the actual value of that property for a given object. You'd need to call `p.GetValue(instanceForWhichToGetThePropertyValue, null)`.

Comment: Where "instanceForWhichToGetThePropertyValue" is the instance of the class? Because I tried this  tables.Add(p.GetValue(obj,null)); where obj is the newed up instance of the class. And I used obj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance); to get the PropertyInfo...and that didnt work

Comment: yeap, `instanceForWhichToGetThePropertyValue` should be instances of your `EquityAndOptionDataRetrievalManager`-class. It would help to see the error you get when you used that.

Comment: I edited the OP to show the whole method that way. There is no "Error" yet as the compiler doesn't accept the line tables.Add(p.GetValue(obj, null))

Comment: because `GetValue` just returns `object`. You have to cast to your class.

Comment: Ok, I added as CloudTable to that line and tested it. See the OP for the error. I also tried instantiating the tables in the constructor, and it produces basically the same error.

Comment: Disregard the last comment, I know why its erring.

Comment: The problem lies in the if test for CloudTable type, see the updated OP

Comment: `p.GetType()` will allways be just `typeof(PropertyInfo)`. You need `p.PropertyType`.

Comment: Thank you, that works and makes sense. Post it and I'll accept.